# Change port of deployed Spring project on Wildfly

Tags: spring, port, wildfly

Note to moderator: Other existing questions in SO make reference to the default interface. I'm not interested on changing that. I need to specifically change the port of each deployment.

Other questions regard wildfly running in standalone mode. I'm running it as a Windows Server Service.

Based on this please do not close the question.

Now, the question:

Taking as a reference the following Spring application, running on Wildfly on Windows Server 2019 installed as a service:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<DemoApplication> applicationClass = DemoApplication.class;


}
```

When I was using Tomcat, changing the web service port was easy as adding:

**Application.properties**

> server.port=8093

Resulting in the desired URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8093/swagger-ui.html
```

However, deploying on Wildfly proved to be harder. At first, it was the .war name and the wrong context root, which I fixed by adding the following changes:

**pom.xml**

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
```

**src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

However, there's the last problem. The web service is being exposed on http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger-ui.html instead of using port 8093.

How can I change the port of each deployed web service in Wildfly, instead of the default 8080?

Comment: As in a separate port per war file?  You'll need a new interface per web app.  But Springboot includes a server (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.) with it.  Deploying a springboot application to sit inside of another server doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's how I temporarily fixed it, creating multiple Wildfly instances one for each war. But I think that's not the correct way (Wildfly offers the management tools to deploy multiple wars inside one instance). We don't want to use Tomcat, had bad experiences with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server.port` property only controls the listening port of an embedded server in a Spring boot app (tomcat, jetty, etc.).

The app's port in a standalone application server is specified during the deployment. The easiest way to do this on Wildfly is via the `wildfly-maven-plugin` (https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html):

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- ... -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                <port>8093</port>       <!-- <<<<<<<< -->
                <username>my-wildfly-user</username>
                <password>my-wildfly-password</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ... -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you very much dekkard. Yes, the server.port was for reference purposes. I saw this wildfly-maven-plugin approach on another site and surely it would made deployment easier. However, according to the site the port specified on ${deploy.jboss.port} was 9900 (the port for the Wilfly management interface. But how could you change the port where the application is deployed?

Comment: You can specify whatever port you like in the `<port></port>` tag. Updated the answer with actual values for clarity.